# How to parse multiple objects in firebase

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

i have a database in Firebase look like:
[image]

and two objects:

```
class Area: NSObject {
let itemRef:FIRDatabaseReference?
var id:String?
var name:String?
var cities : [City] = []
var collapsed: Bool
}
```

and

```
class City: NSObject {
var id:String?
var name:String?
init(_ id:String,_ name: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
}

override init(){

}
```

and this is my parsing code :

```
func makeData(){
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("area")
    ref.observe(.childAdded, with: {
        (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
            print(dictionary)
        }
    })
}
```

I try to parse the data in snapshot to my array Area but i cannot
how i can do it?

Comment: You code refers to a child `arena`, but your JSON doesn't show such a child. Please replace the screenshot of the JSON with the actual text of the JSON and include the node that is referenced in the code. You can get the JSON as text by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like that :

(It's just an example, you need to adapt this for your case)

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("area")

ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
        return
    }

    // Create the area object
    let area = Area()

    // Add id in the area
    area.id = snapshot.key

    // Init cities
    area.cities = [City]()

    if let cities = dictionary["cities"] as? [String: Any] {
        for (key, value) in cities {
            guard let cityName = value["name"] as? String else {
                continue
            }

            // Create the city object
            let city = City(key, cityName)

            // Add city to cities in the area
            area.cities.append(city)
        }
    }

    if let name = dictionary["name"] as? String {
        // Add name in the area
        area.name = name
    }

    // Use the area
})
```

Comment: Thank for your answer but error in this line 
let city = City(key, value as! String)
with error Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x101ffd2b0) to 'NSString' (0x103280c60).

Comment: Try City(key, value["name"] as! String)

Comment: it's work perfect, thank you very much, you are my hero. but i have to change [String: Any] to [Strinng:AnyObjects]